# Python - Regex - Feed one match into another

Tags: python, regex

I've a function that iterates over the parts of a string and if the part is found in a dictionary, replaces it with the key:

```
def normalize(street):
            acronyms = {'AVE':'AVENUE', 'RD': 'ROAD', 'BLVD': 'BOULEVARD', 
            'PKWY': 'PARKWAY','HWY':'HIGHWAY', 'ST': 'STREET',
            'E': 'EAST','W':'WEST','S': 'SOUTH','N': 'NORTH'}
            return [re.sub(r"\b%s\b" %street_part, acronyms[street_part], 
            street) for street_part in street.split() if street_part in 
            acronyms]  

normalize('123 E MAIN AVE')
['123 EAST MAIN AVE', '123 E MAIN AVENUE']
```

Whereas the output needs to be:
['123 EAST MAIN AVENUE']

How can I feed each return value back to the comprehension for further expansion? Or iterate over iterations in the comprehension to get the final expanded address? Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have complicated regex patterns here, I'd recommend just indexing into the dict inside a generator comprehension.

```
In [1051]: acronyms = ...

In [1052]: text = '123 E MAIN AVE'

In [1055]: ' '.join(acronyms.get(x, x) for x in text.split())
Out[1055]: '123 EAST MAIN AVENUE'
```

`acronyms.get(x, x)` returns the replacement if it exists, or just re-echos the original string back.

Comment: @Mokshyam Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as:

```
def normalize(street):
        acronyms = {'AVE':'AVENUE', 'RD': 'ROAD', 'BLVD': 'BOULEVARD',\
                    'PKWY': 'PARKWAY','HWY':'HIGHWAY', 'ST': 'STREET',\
        'E': 'EAST','W':'WEST','S': 'SOUTH','N': 'NORTH'}
        for street_part in street.split():
            if street_part in acronyms:
                street = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" %street_part, acronyms[street_part], street)
        return street
```